# how to create template pages using html javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, phonegap

So I use php for my website and use include/require to add my header and footer to each page but im trying to build an app using phonegap which only allows html css and javascript how do i build a template header and footer without using php

so i have 5 pages that need the same header and footer but different content

how do i do this if i cant use php? or can i? 
open to all suggestions

```
<body>

<header>
This is my header
</header>

<content>
page content
</content>

<footer>
this is my footer
</footer>


</body>
```

Comment: Google "single page app", or SPA. Perfect for Phonegap/Cordova.

Comment: Use a javascript templating engine?... handlebars, pug etc

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, it's possible without any library or without using external html files by dynamically generating the templates using plain javascript. That being the case that means you will have to code your own header/footer mini-module that dynamically renders when called.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, i have add a working example that could fit your needs

Comment: thanks for the responses really helped  me, cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still call a script that generate html code on a special element,

imagine you have a id #header on each page of your application that call your script which insert some greetings looking like this :

```js
document.getElementById("#header").insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<h1>Hello there!</h1>");
```

```html
<div id="#header"></div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

I have made something similar in past :

```
const Component = function(props) {
  this.props = props;

  let _state = {};
  this.setState = state => (_state = state);
  this.getState = () => _state;
};

class Factory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setState({
      template: this.setTemplate(this.props.template), //html
      action: this.props.template[this.props.action], // js
      templateState: this.props.action, // switch beetween html/js
      dom: {
        //dom elements
        header: document.querySelector("#header-pwd"),
        content: document.querySelector("#content-pwd"),
        info: document.querySelector("#info-pwd")
      }
    });

    this.clear(); // clear html
    this.getTemplate(); // insert template into dom
    this.getState().action(); // link onclick elements
  }

  getTemplate() {
    const template = this.getState().template;

    const header = this.getState().dom.header;
    const content = this.getState().dom.content;
    const info = this.getState().dom.info;

    header.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", template.header);
    content.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", template.content);
    info.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", template.info);
  }

  setTemplate(template) {
    const getState = this.getState().templateState
      ? this.getState().templateState
      : this.props.action;
    const objectFilter = Object.keys(template)
      .filter(key => key[0] !== "_")
      .map(
        key =>
          template[key][getState]
            ? template[key][getState]
            : template[key]["_init"]
      );
    return {
      header: objectFilter[0],
      content: objectFilter[1],
      info: objectFilter[2]
    };
  }

  clear() {
    const dom = Object.values(this.getState().dom);
    for (let parent of dom) {
      if (parent.firstChild === null) continue;
      while (parent.firstChild) {
        parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

working with an object like this :

```
const pageTemplate = {
  header: {
    _init: `<h1>my header</h1>`
  },
  content: {
    _init: `<h1>my content</h1>`
  },
  info: {
    _init: `<h1>my footer</h1>`
  },
  _init: () => {
    /* your js logic like onclick action with your knew dom created */
  }
};
new Factory({ template: pageTemplate, action: "_init" });
```

Your html :

```
<div id="header-pwd"></div>
<div id="content-pwd"></div>
<div id="info-pwd"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible without any library or without using external html files by dynamically generating the templates using plain javascript. That being the case that means you will have to code your own header/footer mini-module that dynamically renders when called.

Something like

```
function myHeaderTemplate(){
   let htemplate = {};

   //template properties
   htemplate.props = {title: '', otherProps: ''}

   //template methods
   htemplate.render = function(){
      //generate the html template
      //possibly add custom content
      //use your props here
   }

   //other methods

   return htemplate;
}
```

Then we instantiate this template object in your pages, for example, about.html

```
let header = new myHeaderTemplate();
header.props.title = 'About Header';
//other props and customizable content
header.render();
```

Sadly, this doesn't really exactly give you an answer. Just an idea/possible approach. You will have to employ OOP with this.